# 'where' clause datasource on c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datasource, where-clause

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:arqsi43ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [nome], [votos], [id] FROM [Playlist] WHERE ([semana_votacao] = @semana_votacao)">
   <SelectParameters>
       <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="semana_votacao" 
                QueryStringField="SELECT MAX(id) FROM VotacaoSemana" Type="Int32" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have 2 tables - `PlayList` and `VotacaoSemana`.

I need to show on a gridview all values from `PlayList` that have the attribute `semana_votacao` equal to the max id from table `votacaosemana`.

I used the wizard to try to configure it, but I am doing something wrong, because the gridview is empty...

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write sql queries for `QueryStringField` which is `url query string`. Change your `SelectCommand` as follows and `no need to have parameters`

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT [nome], [votos], [id] FROM [Playlist] 
WHERE [semana_votacao] = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM VotacaoSemana)"
```